# How does the Enterprise maneuver in space?

Tags: star-trek

I know the engines drive the ship through space, but how does the crew steer it? What is it that Sulu, Chekov, and the other navigators are supposed to be controlling when they maneuver the vessel?

[image: pic]

"All right... Everybody *lean*..."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In-universe answer: At impulse and slower speeds they would use some kind of reaction control system (basically, thrusters) or a small-scale version of the impulse engines.  At warp, they would have to alter the shape of the warp field, or drop out of warp, turn as described above, then enter warp again.

Out-of-universe answer: We're used to how airplanes and submarines move, so the way the Enterprise banks and turns looks "natural" to us, when in fact a real spacecraft wouldn't move like that *at all*.  Remember that a lot of the effects shots are based on what *looks good*, not necessarily what's scientifically accurate.

Comment: Do you have some links to corroborate the in-universe answer? Thx

Comment: Maneuvering thrusters are pretty regularly mentioned in the shows when a ship's impulse or warp engines are disabled or otherwise damaged.  From the tech manuals there are Reaction Control systems spread about the ship that used vectored thrust for fine navigational control.

Comment: @DVK: [This page](http://www.cygnus-x1.net/links/lcars/blueprints/enterprise-phase-2-refit-program/enterprise-phase-2-refit-program-sheet-6.jpg) references RCS thruster pylons on the warp nacelles.  And there have been references to thrusters on screen (such as when pulling out of drydock).

Comment: This info should be added to the answer, please.

Comment: When at warp they have to drop out to turn. "Faster than light, no left or right," as Tom Paris said.